# Help to decrese query time in huge table of 100M+ rows on Ms-SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, performance, stored-procedures, query-performance

I am trying to get data using offset limit concept as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE BaseUserIndex
    @Offset int,
    @Limit int,
    @SortCol int,
    @SortDir nvarchar(10),
    @Search nvarchar(255) = NULL
AS BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT id,
    name,
    address,
    city,
    FROM users
    WHERE deleted_at IS NULL
    ORDER BY 
        case when (@SortCol = 0 and @SortDir='asc')
        then name
        end asc,
        case when (@SortCol = 0 and @SortDir='desc')
        then name
        end desc,

        case when (@SortCol = 1 and @SortDir='asc')
        then address
        end asc,
        case when (@SortCol = 1 and @SortDir='desc')
        then address
        end desc,

        case when (@SortCol = 2 and @SortDir='asc')
        then city
        end asc,
        case when (@SortCol = 2 and @SortDir='desc')
        then city
        end desc
    OFFSET @Offset ROWS 
    FETCH NEXT @Limit ROWS ONLY 
END
```

But, this code snippet is taking around 15 sec, to fetch data. Is there any way to improve this?

As I am new to Ms SQL. Is there any way to decrease this?

Comment: Please take a look at [this Q&A](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions) for suggestions on what information is necessary for us to be able to help you.

Comment: Have a look here: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/01/dynamic-sorting/

Answer (score 1):

To make this work well you need to create a separate query for each sort order, and have indexes that support the OFFSET .. FETCH without needing to sort the whole table first.  For the query part you can use `IF` statements with static SQL, or dynamic SQL.  Here's how to do this with some filtered indexes and dynamic SQL:

```
--drop table if exists users
go
create table users(id int primary key, name nvarchar(200), address nvarchar(200), city nvarchar(200), deleted_at datetime2 null)
go
create index ix_users_city on users(city) where deleted_at is null
create index ix_users_name on users(name) where deleted_at is null
create index ix_users_address on users(address) where deleted_at is null
go

CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE BaseUserIndex
    @Offset int,
    @Limit int,
    @SortCol int,
    @SortDir nvarchar(10),
    @Search nvarchar(255) = NULL
AS BEGIN
/*
  exec BaseUserIndex 0,100,2,'asc'
*/
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    declare @sql nvarchar(max) = concat(N'
    SELECT id,
    name,
    address,
    city
    FROM users
    WHERE deleted_at IS NULL
    ORDER BY ',
        case 
        when (@SortCol = 0 and @SortDir='asc')  then N'name asc'
        when (@SortCol = 0 and @SortDir='desc') then N'name desc'
        when (@SortCol = 1 and @SortDir='asc')  then N'address asc'
        when (@SortCol = 1 and @SortDir='desc') then N'address desc'
        when (@SortCol = 2 and @SortDir='asc')  then N'city asc'
        when (@SortCol = 2 and @SortDir='desc') then N'city desc'
        end
        ,N'
    OFFSET ', @Offset, N' ROWS 
    FETCH NEXT ', @Limit, N' ROWS ONLY'
    )

    --print @sql
    exec ( @sql )

END
```